# JWPlayer onComplete show a pop-up

Tags: jquery, popup, video-streaming, jwplayer

I am using jQuery and JWPlayer on a page where the video is being played. When the video ends I would like to show an overlay pop-up with CTA.

In documentation I have found that onComplete() call could be used for that, but I can't find any info on how to fire up a pop-up...

Is it possible at all? If yes, how do I show an overlay sort of pop-up once the video finished playing?

Comment: Hi.. I am facing 1 issue. My video is playing in loop. I want to stop this feature. How can I do?

Comment: create your own question please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is example to CTA onComplete:

http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/call-to-action-with-jw-player/

You can view the code in this page:
http://demo.jwplayer.com/cta-overlay/

Another option is to use other jquery lightbox plugin and use onComplete() to fire pop-up

```
    jwplayer().onComplete(function(){/*your jquery function*/})
```

Comment: @Ben seems like this method doesn’t work on Samsung's Android browser. Any idea why?

Comment: Could you share your link where you run the player?